# Search file to locate the drive

Tags: batch

I tried to use below script to search which drive is the file located but it could not echo the results. Please help to see where went wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
for /f tokens^=1*delims^=: %%i in ('
fsutil fsinfo drives')do set "_drvs=%%~j"

for /f tokens^=*^delims^=? %%i in ('
call dir/b/a-d/s %_drvs:\=\BatchScripts.txt% 2^>nul 
')do set "_fpath=%%~dpi" && set "_file=%%~dfi" && set "_drive=%%~di" && goto %:^)

%:^)
echo\Use "%_fpath%" and "%_file%" and "%_drive%"

PAUSE
```

[image]

New and modification

```
if exist D:\sources\sxs\ (
echo The source drive is Drive D
pause
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:D:\sources\sxs /NoRestart
) else (
if exist E:\sources\sxs\ (
echo The source drive is Drive E
pause
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:E:\sources\sxs /NoRestart
) else (
if exist F:\sources\sxs\ (
echo The source drive is Drive F
pause
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:F:\sources\sxs /NoRestart
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the file you're trying to search is the ***letter*:\sources\sxs** folder and you're trying to find the drive it is located on, right?
If yes, I can suggest you to do this:

```
:scan
for %%a in ( A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ) do (
    if /i exist ”%%a:\sources\sxs\” (
        echo The source letter drive is Drive %%a:
        pause
        rem here you will put commands that are executed only in the case that \sources\sxs\ is found on the "%%a" drive
        goto :success
        rem make sure to add a "success" label when the drive is found and the commands are executed to exit from the loop
    )
)
echo No drive seems to contain the \sources\sxs folder...
echo Press ENTER to scan again
pause>nul
goto :scan
:success
echo Operation completed successfully!
pause
exit
```

I'm sorry if I'm mistaken, I'm new to superuser and I can't leave comments yet. I would have left one to make sure I understood the question but I can't yet.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Can I still use %%a this strring valueable to run this command : dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:%%a:\sources\sxs /NoRestart

Comment: Bear in mind that %%a is just the "current" letter, and it skips to the next letter once the cycle is completed. Each time the cycle is completed but Z is not reached yet, the loop stores the next letter into the %%a variable. You can use %%every-letter-you-like but keep in mind that %%g is different from %%G.
But yeah, as the programs finds "%%a/sources/sxs" it enters the IF clause, so you can execute any command using the %%variable.
(_EDIT: you can delete from the list all the letters you don't want to scan._)

Comment: What is the meaning or purpose to use /i in if function ?

Comment: /i makes the IF clause not case-sensitive (it makes no difference between "this", "THIS" and "tHIs": I know that in this case there's no point to put it but it's just nice to have it to make things tidier)

Comment: Thank you so much. 

Comment: You're welcome :) glad to help!